# How to shift the border of a text?

Tags: css, text

[image]I would like to shift the border of a text, I've already made the text with the border.

```
h1 {
  font-size: 35pt;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Josefin Sans';
  color: #e89cab;
  -webkit-text-stroke: 1.72px;
  -webkit-text-stroke-color: #0500ff;
}
```

Comment: text-shadow property

Answer (score 0):

```
h1 {
    font-size: 35pt;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'Josefin Sans';
    color: transparent;
    -webkit-text-stroke: 1.62px;
    -webkit-text-stroke-color: #0500ff;
    text-shadow: 3px 1px pink;
}
```

Comment: Is this an answer or did you want to update your question?

Answer (score 0):

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <style> 
    h1 {
     font-family: sans-serif;
        font-size: 80pt;
        -webkit-text-stroke: 2px #0500ff;
        color: transparent;
        text-shadow: 6px 5px 0 #e89cab;
    }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Notre Plateau</h1>
    </body>
    </html>
```